# Can I operate the Yard Stick One on Windows?

Tags: windows

I recently ordered a [Yard Stick One](http://www.nooelec.com/store/yard-stick-one-bundle.html). I am quite new to programming and SDR. I would like to know if can operate the yardstick one on Windows? Some people tell me they can only operate on Linux.

Comment: first, it would have been nice if you had linked to the product you were talking about, second, this is a question for the vendor, but the answer is very likely that it cannot be used on such a hardware-limited OS